How can I make a drop-down field to display a record in a database in Django. e.g. If I select a Last Name it displays the associated record
I am trying to display a record of a database after a user has selected the record from a dropdown list of one of the fields of the table (in Django). So far I have only seen examples of selecting data from other tables.
I have a model:class Customer(models.Model):
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
customer_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
business_name = models.CharField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

and a view:
  def customer_record(request):
    customers = Customer.objects.all()  
    return render(request, 'customer_record.html', {'customers':customers})

and a form
class Meta:
model = Customer
fields = ('customer_number', 'business_name',   'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
labels = {'business_name':'',
'first_name':'',
'last_name':'',
'email':'',}
and the html:
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
<option selected>Open this select menu</option>

    {% if customers %}

    {% for customer in customers %}
        
        <option value={{ customer.last_name }} ></option>
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}

    </select>

 

Trying the above, I get the dropdown that says: "Open the select menu", and then blank spaces in the dropdown corresponding, I believe, to the number of records I have. I expected to see the last names appear in the dropdown. Once selected, I would like to then display the record.

I just realized that I needed to display the value in the field. e.g. <option value={{ customer.last_name }} > {{ customer.last_name}} This works, but now it displays ==Smith. How do I get rid of the ==, and then also show the record?

Update: using bootstrap: 

Dropdown


    {%for customer in customers %}
     
    {% endfor %}
  

This gives me the dropdown list of the names. How to select them and populate the form from the data in the customer table?